# BigQuery - Extract first non-null value from JSON collection

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

Here is how my collection looks:

[image]

What I would like to is to get a first non-null value from it, something like `json-coalesce(my_collection,"$")` returing `5` in the first case and `true` in the second.

What's the best way to do this without handling each key individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
create temp function values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
""";
select my_collection,
  ( select val
    from unnest(values(my_collection)) val with offset
    where not val is null
    order by offset
    limit 1
  ) as first_not_null_value
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not a general solution, but using a regex,

```sql
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_EXTRACT(json, r'(?U):\s*([^(null)].*)\s*[,}]'), '"') non_null 
  FROM sample;
```

**assumption:** a value is a primitive type, i.e. integer, string.

output will be:

[image]