# BigQuery: Count non-null values across all columns with REGEX

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have the following query that helps me count how many null values were reported in each column across all columns of a table in BQ:

```
SELECT col_name, COUNT(1) nulls_count
FROM table t,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"(\w+)":null')) col_name
GROUP BY col_name 
;
```

I need to adjust it so it counts the non-null values. I tried to use negative lookahead but it doesn't seem to work.
My end goal is to indicate wether a certain column reports at least 1 non-null value.

Input example (the table):

[image]

Output example:

[image]

column_c is not present since all of its values are nulls.

Comment: Negetive lookahead is not supported in regex extract in bigquery. Could you provide sample input and output to replicate?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan Examples added.

Comment: hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72833048/bigquery-extract-first-non-null-value-from-json-collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, (without REGEX) solution

```
select * from (select column, countif(val!= 'null') non_null
from `dataset.table` table1
,unnest(array( 
  select as struct trim(ar[offset(0)], '"') column, trim(ar[offset(1)], '"') val
  from unnest(split(trim(to_json_string(table1), '{}'))) pb,
  unnest([struct(split(pb, ':') as ar)])
)) record
group by column) where non_null!=0
```

output:

[image]